# can't use child props in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a problem with the code - I do not understand how to solve it - I tried for a few hours - it does not work.

I do not know what's going on. I'm just trying to access from a component of courses - and a component of a single course.

I get this error:

[image]

This is the code I wrote down so far - not a long code.

course.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Course extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>this.props.location.title</h1>
                <p>You selected the Course with ID: {this.props.match.params.id}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Course;
```

courses.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './Courses.css';

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Courses extends Component {
    state = {
        courses: [
            { id: 1, title: 'Angular - The Complete Guide' },
            { id: 2, title: 'Vue - The Complete Guide' },
            { id: 3, title: 'PWA - The Complete Guide' }
        ]
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Amazing Udemy Courses</h1>
                <section className="Courses">
                    {
                        this.state.courses.map(course => {
                            return (
                                <Link
                                    key={course.id}
                                    to={{
                                        pathname: this.props.match.url + "/" + course.id,
                                        title: course.title
                                    }}>
                                    <article className="Course">{course.title}</article>
                                </Link>
                             )
                        })
                    }
                </section>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Courses;
```

app.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Courses from './containers/Courses/Courses';
import Users from './containers/Users/Users';
import { NavLink, BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <header>
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <NavLink
                    to="/users"
                    exact
                    activeClassName="my-active"
                    activeStyle={{
                      color: '#fa923f',
                      textDecoration: 'underline'
                    }}>Users
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <NavLink to={{
                    pathname: '/courses',
                    hash: '#submit',
                    search: '?quick-submit=true'
                  }}>Courses
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </header>


          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
            </Route>
            <Route path="/users">
              <Users />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/courses">
              <Courses />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
          <ol style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>
            <li>Pass the course ID to the "Course" page and output it there</li>
            <li>Pass the course title to the "Course" page - pass it as a param or score bonus points by passing it as query params (you need to manually parse them though!)</li>
            <li>Load the "Course" component as a nested component of "Courses"</li>
            <li>Add a 404 error page and render it for any unknown routes</li>
            <li>Redirect requests to /all-courses to /courses (=> Your "Courses" page)</li>
          </ol>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thank you for help, I think I get the match automatically using BrowserRouter, am I wrong?

Comment: You should read the documentation of react router better. `math` is only passed as an argument if you use `component=`, if you use `children` like you are doing now you have to pass it manually. I would suggest never using `children` with react router because it is a bit broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access the props that come from react router, with the syntax that you're using on your app.js file you're not passing any props. To be able to pass react router props to your component you can use this syntax instead:

```
<Route path="/courses" component={Courses} />
```

So everytime you access a link that takes you to the courses you will have available in you component all the props that are coming from react router.

Here's a sandbox with an example of a component that uses that syntax to obtain all the router props vs another that uses the syntax you're using and it does not have access to the router props:
[Sandbox with example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-worker-kvxxg)

I'm using functional components but with your example doing this.props will give the router props including the match object. With your courses component being a class I think this is the easiest way to do it, you can also wrap the component in a withRouter HOC to accomplish the same thing:
[WIth router docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, it works, right now when I try to open a link at a new address it's not working. I can not run the component of course.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set props in your child components for them to be available, like so...

```
<Courses
    match={this.props.match}
/>
```

Right now, all you have is `<Courses />`, without passing an props.  So in the `Courses` class, of course you'll get this message: `Cannot read property 'url' of undefined` on your call of `<Link ....this.props.match.....>`.

But if you pass along the `match` prop, like `match={this.props.match}`, there should no longer be this error.

Take a look at the ReactJS documentation on how props work...

> However, elements can also represent user-defined components:
>
> `const element = <Welcome name="Sara" />;`
>
> When React sees an element representing a user-defined component, it passes JSX attributes and children to this component as a single object. ***We call this object “props”.***

Source: [***ReactJS.org: Components and Props***](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I added the component within the route - it's working right now. But I can not run the component of course.